# How is it possible to mass update a broken link accross SO?

Tags: discussion, edits, broken-link, link-rot, serial-edits

Sometimes, links point to sites which are dead, or not what they used to be, thus are broken.

Sometimes, those sites do have mirrors.

Is it possible to update all broken links in the various comments, questions and/or answers massively, to change to the still working mirror?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Surely that's 1 too many?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Try searching for [`url:"*exampledepot.com*"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*exampledepot.com*%22+) - There are 756.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards you missed an asterisk in [your query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"*.exampledepot.com*").

Comment: Nope, @rekire, I had an extra dot as animuson pointed out...

Comment: @Oded, almost definitely :-)

Comment: umm... that site you posted now redirect to something "Russian Brides". I didn't dare keeping it open. Can you please find a better example of dead site? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried the two links in my post and I didn't find any "Russian Brides". Which site did you visit?

Comment: [This](http://exampledepot.com/) redirects to http://ww1.exampledepot.com/?pid=9PO844006 which now I realized sending me to random websites, some NSFW, some are scams (the "upgrade your antivirus now" type, which is of course a virus itself), none is good.

Comment: Anyway, edited now to make it generic. No need for specific example.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks to ABP, I didn't have the chance to see the "Russian Brides" ^^

Comment: lol, no worry I'm sure you didn't miss anything in there. :D